# Oracle database DNS resolution for UTL_HTTP taking time

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am having problem in making UTL_HTTP call from Oracle DB. When I am using IP based URL results are coming fast, but when using DNS based URL 1 out of 10 request is taking extra 5 sec for calling URL.

Below is the sample code

```
declare 
l_url   VARCHAR2(500) := 'SOMEURL';
l_http_request   UTL_HTTP.req;
l_http_response  UTL_HTTP.resp;
BEGIN
DBMS_output.put_line(systimestamp);
FOR i IN 1..100 LOOP 
     -- Make a HTTP request and get the response.
     l_http_request  := UTL_HTTP.begin_request(l_url);
     l_http_response := UTL_HTTP.get_response(l_http_request);
     UTL_HTTP.end_response(l_http_response);
     --DBMS_output.put_line (l_http_response.status_code);
  END LOOP;
DBMS_output.put_line(systimestamp);
END;
/
```

Comment: https://blogs.oracle.com/cloud-infrastructure/post/how-to-remediate-application-slowness-due-to-incomplete-dns-resolutions